# Grouping and summing with r

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that contains two columns that I want to group and sum the direct labor for employees.

```
Employees   Actual work
Joe Smo      8
Joe Smo      7
Joe Smo      5
Sam Adams    7
Sam Adams    5
Sam Adams    3
```

The desired outcome is

```
Results:
Joe Smo      20
Sam Adams    15
```

Here is the code I used that doesn't work.

```
aggregate(directLaborNov18[c('Employee')], directLaborNov18['Actual_work'], sum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. Just switch the first two input arguments.

```
> aggregate(directLaborNov18['Actual_work'], directLaborNov18[c('Employee')],  sum)
   Employee Actual_work
1   Joe Smo          20
2 Sam Adams          15
```